# Npm run build failed to compile due to background image url

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, build

When i'm trying to deploy my react app through the command **"npm run build"** I got the following:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/assets/scss/style.scss
Error: Can't resolve '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-icons/images/welcome-image.jpg'
```

So as you can see its an error related with the `welcome-image.jpg`. This is how I'm calling it in `style.scss` (**this works in development**):

```
.home-image-container {
  background-image: url("../images/welcome-image.jpg");
}
```

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I have two `welcome-image.jpg` because after the error I tried to call the image from the public folder:

```
.home-image-container {
  background-image: url("/welcome-image.jpg");
}
```

This is supposed to work according to some forums that I have seen, since with this url it should go directly to the public folder. However for me it appear that its not getting in to the public folder, I deduce this from the error message:

```
Failed to compile.
Error: Can't resolve '../../welcome-image.jpg'
```

So what I can guess from here  that when I'm putting the url like:`"/welcome-image.jpg"` It should go to the public folder, but its not reaching it, according to the error its going two folders up, so its going to **src** file and not the **Public**.

Finally I decided to do the call of the image directly from the public folder:

```
.home-image-container {
  background-image: url("../../../public/welcome-image.jpg");
}
```

And again, I got another error:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/welcome-image.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

I don't really know what should I do next to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you compiling your scss files? Also, you are using Create React App, right?

Comment: can you please try `background-image: url("./welcome-image.jpg");`